# is this possible to call the Appconfig value as an Object?

Tags: c#

I have the below method in my dll class library

```
 private void Download(string filename)
    {
     //am calling this value from appconfig
string ftpserverIp = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerAddress"];
    //    somecode to download the file
    }

    Private void Upload(string filename)
    {
string ftpserverIp = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerAddress"];
    //    somecode to upload the file
    }
```

Like that am getting all the values from appconfig for all my methods,is this any efficient way to call appconfig values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be costly at runtime.

However it will be a maintenance issue for maintaining the code. Perhaps a property would be beneficial.

```
private string ServerAddress 
{
   get { return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerAddress"]; }
}
private void Download(string filename)
{
 // Use ServerAddress
//    somecode to download the file
}

Private void Upload(string filename)
{

//    somecode to upload the file
}
```

The next logical step would be to write a custom configuration section.

Answer (score 1):

How about a private getter to save on typing/copy'n'pasting:

```
private string FtpServerIp
{
    get
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerAddress"];
    }
}
```

Comment: wow! awesome for all your input,i will go with private getter.

Answer (score 1):

That's the preferred way to access the `AppSettings` section of the config files. If you're concerned for unit testing purposes you could have those values injected from the config in a parent container or class and then you could use values for testing.  Or you could have a separate config in your unit test project.

Answer (score 1):

I generally create a class for all items in my appsettings section of my config e.g.

```
public class ConfigSettings  
{
    public static string ServerAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerAddress"];
        }
    }

    public static string OtherSetting
    {
        get
        {
            return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OtherSetting"];
        }
    }
}
```

and then to use it:

```
string address = ConfigSettings.ServerAddress;
```

Answer (score 0):

AppSettings are cached - so it is efficient to call them that way.